# how to php query and encode to json level 2

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my database table

```
Questions Table
id | qname                           | ansid
1  | 1.what's your favorite color ?  |  a-01
2  | 2.what's your hair color ?      |  a-01
```

```
Answer Table
id | ansid | aname
1  | a-01  | red
2  | a-01  | blue
3  | a-01  | green
```

when i use php query and encode to json

```
 select * from questions inner join answers on question.ansid = answer.ansid
```

```
 [
     {
       "question": "1. What's your favorite color ?",
       "choices": [{"a": "red"}]
     },
     {
       "question": "1. What's your favorite color ?",
       "choices": [{"a": "blue"}]
     },
     {
       "question": "1. What's your favorite color ?",
       "choices": [{"a": "green"}]
     },
     {
       "question": "2. what's your hair color ?",
       "choices": [{"a": "red"}]
     },
     {
       "question": "2. what's your hair color ?",
       "choices": [{"a": "blue"}]
     },
     {
       "question": "2. what's your hair color ?",
       "choices": [{"a": "green"}]
     }
    ]
```

Is it possible to encode json data like

```
[
 {
  "question": "1. What's your favorite color ?",
  "choices": [{"a": "red"},{"a": "blue"},{"a": "green"}]
 },
 {
  "question": "2. What's your hair color ?",
  "choices": [{"a": "red"},{"a": "blue"},{"a": "green"}]
 }
]
```

Comment: You have json data but you also seem to be doing sql queries. How are they related? This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: How is the SQL query related to your JSON data? I don't understand your 2nd part of question. At all, isn't better to restructure your JSON data and keep all choices as a array at one question?

Comment: @JaxCze you're just guessing what the OP wants. Let her explain her problem first in a way that others can understand. Currenly it's just one big confusion...

Comment: They might be related as MySQL supports storing JSON values. Could you please be more precise? What's your DB schema? Are you using any ORM/library to get that?

Comment: Can you show your data in PHP? How do you retrieve or construct it before encoding?

Comment: you just need two array main and sub and then do json encode.

Comment: I think he's just asking for a different query. The JSON part is somewhat unrelated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this in two queries like below-

```
// first select questions with your criteria for me limiting to 20
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions limit ?");
 $stmt = $stmt->execute([20]);
 $questions = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 //collect ansid 
 $ansIds = [];
 foreach($questions as $qst)
 {
     $ansIds[] = $qst['ansid'];
 }

 $ansIds = array_unique($ansIds);

// now collect answers belongs above questions

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE ansis in (?)");
$stmt = $stmt->execute([implode(",", $ansIds)]);
$answers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// now combine them having loop like below
// pass by reference in foreach
 foreach($questions as &$question)
 {
     $question['choices'] = [];
     foreach($answers as $ans)
     {
        if($question['ansid'] == $ans["ansid"])
        {
          array_push($question['choices'], ['a' => $ans['aname']]);
        }
     }
 }
// now your $questions variable is ready 

 echo json_encode($questions);
```

Comment: this is my error 'Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in '

Comment: oh sorry , its json_encode, @ThanyaRattana, edited my answer please check. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for a different query to get the desired result and it's somewhat unrelated to the JSON part.

Given your schema [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b292c9/8) I've prepared a couple of queries over there.

The short answer is: No you can't do that. There are Database-specific ways to do some collection aggregation over the n-side of a query, however I do not recommend it at all, since the way this is done highly depends on the database you're using and hence you're loosing the portability of your query if you choose to do so.

The cleanest approach would be the fetch the questions first:

```sql
SELECT ansid, qname FROM questions;
```

and then once you've got all the `ansid`'s you can iterate over your results and for each result fetch the answer options:

```sql
SELECT id, aname FROM answers WHERE ansid = 'a-01';
```

Lastly you just need to merge the two together to get your desired output.